# Why should I click twice for keypress when I put keypress event in click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
var main = function() {
    $('.article').click(function() {
        $(document).keypress(function(event) {
            if (event.which === 111) {
                $('.current').children('.description').toggle();
            } 
        });
        $('.article').removeClass('current');
        $('.description').hide();
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $(this).children('.description').show();
    });
    
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

This is a practice from codecademy (The o Shorcut). I just can't figure out why should I click twice then I am able to trigger `keypress` event. (I know I can put `keypress` event outside click event, and then I can `keypress` <kbd>o</kbd> when I click just once, yet I still want to know the answer of this issue.)

Comment: No you don't need to click twice, only one time. Now please try to replicate issue, works as expected here: https://jsfiddle.net/15gckeaq/

Comment: On which browser? Because on chrome, i still have to click only once

Comment: Yes, it needs only one click.

Comment: @A.Wolff I've update the link in [link](https://jsfiddle.net/15gckeaq/1/), and you can tried to click in different article. You need to click twice when you want to use 'o' key event.

Comment: I've already checked it and NO it only needs one click... Now i don't know how to say that...  So on which browser/OS are you testing it **???**  EDIT: wait: sounds i was able to replicate issue, need more tests

Comment: Ok i see, this is because if you click an article after already clicked one, you are binding two click handlers, and so calling `toggle()` twice. It would then, show it and hide it. That's a good reason you shouldn't nesting events...

Comment: @A.Wolff 1. click the first article, 2. press 'o'. You can press 'o' when you do this. Then 3. press the second article. 4. press 'o'. You **can't** trigger 'o' event when you press it. 5. Then click the next article. 6. press 'o'. You can press 'o' in this time. And you can't press 'o' again when you click the next article, yet you **can** press 'o' when you click next article **twice**.  I can replicate this issue in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @LeoHsieh I explained it. First time you click, you are binding one keypress event. Pressing 'O' will call `toggle()` once, showing description. If you then click an article again, it would bind again a keypress event, so you will call `toggle()` twice. If decription is hidden, it would give `description.toggle().toggle()` so it is still hidden. Now you know WHY you shouldn't nest events...

Comment: @LeoHsieh Ok my previous comment had a typo, it was `you are binding two click handlers` but should be `you are binding two keypress handlers`. Each time you click article, you are binding new keypress event

Comment: @A.Wolff Ok I see, it seems like nest event is dangerous... Every time when I click one article, it will just add a click event. So if I click a lot of times, it will generates bunch of events in the backgroud...  Thx for your help.